# Unit testing failing due to 0.000000001f inaccuarcy

Tags: c#, unit-testing

A vector is out by 0.000000001f so the test is failing.

Doing the logic in my head yeilds -1.0f, -1.0f but when I wrote the code to pass the test (Using the built in Vector methods) the answer comes back as -0.999999999f, -0.999999999f which is still 'right'.

This is C# (Vector2 class provided by the XNA framework) by the way, so I tried adding an epsilon value to each the x and y parameter of the Vector but this didn't work.

The way I see it is that by coding the answer, I'm writing the production code. E.g. it would be the same. Surely this is not the right.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken/588014#588014).

It is not about C#, but the same logic applies.

Answer (score 6):

Unit testing frameworks usually provide asserts for floats that take a precision. For example in Visual Studio Test you can write:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1.0f, 0.9999999999f, 1e-3); // passes
Assert.AreEqual(1.0f, 0.9f, 1e-3); // fails
```

Comment: Its NUnit. The code is not accessible at the moment. Does anyone know if NUnit has something similar?

Comment: Yes, NUnit has the same concept: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalityAsserts&r=2.2.7

Comment: After all Microsoft haven't reinvented the wheel :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using an epsilon value should work, you could post the code that doesn't work to make your problem clearer. You should do something like this:

```
if ((TestSomething()->Vector.x - 1.0f) <= EPSILON) return true;
```

instead of

```
if (TestSomething()->Vector.x = 1.0f) return true;
```

Comment: You forgot the Math.Abs() around the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers can have precision issues, besides comparison to 0 you rarely would want to compare two floating point numbers using ==.

Trying to add an epsilon value to the vectors won't work - you'll still fall for the same precision issues.

Instead, you need to see if the difference between the two is below some threshold:

```
if (Math.Abs(x - y) < epsilon)
{
     // Equal!
}
```